# multiple input in checkbox for different data and ID

Tags: javascript, laravel

Good day guys...

Currently working a project in Laravel. **The problem is I want to put an input `checkbox` in different data with its different `ID` by the Date** for example in this date of `aug 1` I have 10 records of data and checked only 4 records when I checked the checkbox through by date, it save only in 1 id as a whole rather than saving each checked 4 records in its different `dataID`.

**Controller** (checkbox):

```
 public function dsmed(Request $request)
{
    $datab = new check();

    $datab->data_id = $request->data_id;
    $datab->check = implode("/",$request->check);

    $datab->save();

    Session::flash('success','SAVE!');

    return back();
}
```

**Controller** (view by date):

```
public function sampl(Request $request)
{
    $start = $request->input('start');
    $end = $request->input('end');

    $dataview = data::whereBetween('date_received', array($start, $end))
    ->orderBy('date_received' ,'desc')->get();

    return view ('Med.sampl', compact('dataview'));
}
```

**Blade**:

```
@foreach($dataview as $d)
     <td> <a href="rec/{{$d->id}}" class="btn btn-default"><strong>View</strong></a> </td>
     <td> {{ date ("M j, Y", strtotime($d->date_received)) }} </td>
     <td> {{ $d->number }} </td>
     <td> {{ $d->name }} </td>
     <td> {{ $d->Service }} </td>
     <td> {{ $d->room }} </td>
     <td> {{ date ("M j, Y", strtotime($d->created_at)) }}</td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="1"> <input type="hidden" name="data_id"  value="{{$d->id}}"></td>
    </tbody>
@endforeach
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to edit `<td><input type="checkbox" name="check{{id}}[]" value="1"> <input type="hidden" name="data_id"  value="{{$d->id}}"></td>`
Hope this helps